# Defining procedures in algorithmic

Tags: indentation, algorithms

Is there any support for procedures/methods in the `algorithmic` package? Of course one could use several algorithms to define each method/procedure however because LaTeX usually doesn't put more than three float environments on one page the environments have the bad behaviour to appear pages after they are mentioned. Perhaps there isn't a command that handles this, however I am quite sure there must be an elegant workaround.

Comment: I would suggest you to use the [algorithmicx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) package instead; this package offers you increased functionality (predefined blocks for procedures and functions, for example).

Comment: That's a nice solution for this problem. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! If it's OK with you, I'll post my comment as an answer so you can accept it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the [algorithmicx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) package instead; this package offers you increased functionality (predefined blocks for procedures and functions and the possibility to define your own customized blocks, for example).